# AWS Certification Guide Wiley ACSM FIle Download Issue

Tags: aws

I just purchased the Wiley AWS CErtification Guide but, it did not say it only works with acsm files on windows or MAC, but, I only have ubuntu 16.04. Is there any alternative for this?
Thanks

Comment: You can use the free Adobe Digital Editions in Wine, but I'm not sure offhand how well the newest version works in Wine. That's your best bet if it works ok. If you have an Android tablet, you can use the free Bluefire Reader in Android.

Comment: The Redmill Injector extension for Chrome claims to handle acsm files, but I haven't tried it and don't know anything else about it.

Comment: Here's another idea: Microsoft makes free VM's of Windows available for development. Get one of those (google). Install Adobe Digital Editions in it (requires a free Adobe account). Then re-download or transfer the acsm file to open with ADE and read. Only limititation will be whether or not your computer can run VM's well enough.